# Proof makes sense?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

$\exists! {A} \subset {Z}$ such that $A \cup B = A$, where $B$ is any subset of $Z$.

Proof:

Assume two such sets exist, $A_1$ and $A_2$

If $A_1 \cup B = A_1, \forall B \cup Z$, then $A_1 = Z$

If $A_2 \cup B = A_2, \forall B \cup Z$, then $A_2 = Z$

Thus $A_1 = Z = A_2$

Hence, only one such unique set $A$ exists which is $Z$.

Comment: Since $A\cup B=A\iff B\subseteq A$, it's easy to find counterexamples. **Edit:** My interpretation is that the claim to prove is $$\forall Z\forall B\left(B\in \mathcal P(Z)\implies \exists !A\in \mathcal P(Z)(A\cup B=A)\right).$$

Comment: It seems to me that the original problem is consistent with showing that $A$ must equal $Z$, as the OP did. What do you think is a counterexample?

Comment: @GregMartin The statement I've written in my comment is false. To see this that $Z$ almost any set and $B=\varnothing$. In addition to being false, the statement I typed is my interpretation of what the OP is trying to prove, which may be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume your problem statement means $\exists!A\subseteq Z\;\forall B\subseteq Z\;(A\cup B=A)$ where $Z$ is an arbitrary set.

We'll show that the unique $A$ is $Z$.

Clearly, for any $B\subseteq Z$, $Z\cup B=Z$. So that demonstrates the existence of $A$.

To see that it is unique, assume two such sets exist and call them $A_1$ and $A_2$.
Then, $\forall B\subseteq Z\;(A_1\cup B=A_1)$ and $\forall B\subseteq Z\;(A_2\cup B=A_2)$.

As you've deduced, this implies for $B=Z$, $A_1\cup Z=A_1$ and $A_2\cup Z=A_2$. Since the left-hand sides are equal to $Z$, we can conclude their equality and hence prove uniqueness.

Comment: Up voted for clarity. Note, however, that if you just take $A_1$ such that $\forall B\subseteq Z\;(A_1\cup B=A_1)$, by instantiating  $B=Z$, you get $Z=A_1$. The second set is unnecessary.

Comment: @GitGud Agreed. In this case, proving $\exists x\,(P(x)\land \forall y\,(P(y) \implies y=x))$ will lead to a more concise proof than the one by $\exists x\,P(x) \land \forall y\,\forall z\, ((P(y)\land P(z))\implies y=z)$.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the way to interpret the statement is this: For every set $Z$ there exists a unique subset $A$ such that $A\cup B = A$ for all subsets $B$ of $Z$. Note that this means that this is equivalent to saying that there is a unique subset $A$ of $Z$ which contains all other subsets of $A$ since $A \cup B = B$ is the same as $B\subseteq A$. (You should convince yourself of this.)

It is clear that $Z$ fills these requirements so there is at least one such subset.

Your job now is to show that it is the only one. Instead of assuming the existence of to such subsets it might be a bit more clear if you just assume the existence of one and then show that it must equal $Z$. That is the only part you really have to prove and above you just state that it is obvious.

Here is a short proof:

Let $A\subseteq Z$ be a subset that contains all other subsets of $Z$. All you have to prove is that $Z\subseteq A$. (That is, that any element of $Z$ must be an element of $A$.) Let $z$ be an element of $Z$. Then $\{z\}$ is a subset of $Z$ and so we must have that $\{z\}\subseteq A$. That means that $z\in A$ and the proof is done.